# Gas cost of a Message Call

Tags: gas, evm, yellow-paper, message

I was trying to calculate the cost of a message call (CALL, DELEGATECALL, CALLCODE) following the yellow paper but I've not been able to fully understand it.

[image]

It seems that `Ccallgas` is an isolated formula not linked to the `Ccall` formula. My guess is that there is an error and the `Ccall` formula should be:

`Ccall = Ccallgas + Cextra` instead of `Ccall = Cgascap + Cextra`

Am I right? I don't understand either the meaning of `gascap`